# Get values from SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am writing that post because i'm trying to solve a problem which seems to be stupid but unfortunately i cannot make it. I have an XML file (link) which i'm parsing with `simplexml_load_file($link)` as below:

```
function getListPoints($countryCode,$nbrPoints)
{

$xml_containt_url = "http://openchargemap.org/api/?output=xml&countrycode=".$countryCode."&maxresults=".$nbrPoints;

$xml_output = simplexml_load_file($xml_containt_url);


return $xml_output;
}
```

So when I print the xml output:

```
$infos_point = getListPoints("US",2);
print($infos_point);
```

I get everything I want, it gives me :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object

(

[ChargePoint] => Array

    (

        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object

            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 2381
                        [UUID] => BFE199D5-07D4-4310-86D7-8BCB9092541D
                        [DateLastConfirmed] => 31/08/2010 00:00:00
                        [OperatorID] => 1
                        [OperatorTitle] => (Unknown Operator)
                        [DataProviderID] => 2
                        [NumberOfPoints] => 
                        [DataQualityLevel] => 1
                        [PercentageSimilarity] => 
                    )

                [GeneralComments] => 1 SP Inductive
                [AddressInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [LocationTitle] => Sacramento County Public Garage
                        [AddressLine1] => 725 7th St
                        [AddressLine2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [Town] => Sacramento
                        [StateOrProvince] => CA
                        [Postcode] => 95814
                        [Country] => United States
                        [Latitude] => 38.5846
                        [Longitude] => -121.4961
                        [ContactTelephone1] => 916-874-6227
                        [AccessComments] => 24 hours daily; pay lot
                        [RelatedURL] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                    )
```

The problem appears when i want to get some values of the SimpleXMLElement object, for example, I want to get the Town value, so I proceed as it follows :

```
$Town = $infos_point->ChargePoint[0]->AdressInfo->Town;
print($Town);
```

And it gives me a blank page. I have tried everything I've read on the internet and still nothing. 
Maybe somebody can tell me what's happening ? it would be great as i will be able to continue my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your spelling of adDress. Should be: `$Town = $infos_point->ChargePoint[0]->AddressInfo->Town;`